# How to get the controller logic for this directive to run when the modal is opened and recognize the attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that contains a directive. On opening the modal, the directive controller logic is never called. The page renders as much as it can, without any data to work with, but it doesn’t seem to ever run the controller. The controller is called before the modal is opening and still contains the same information from before it was open.

```
<div id=“book-edit-modal" class="modal hide fade hs-full-page-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-body">

        <book-designer></book-designer>

    </div>

</div>
```

Additionally, I’m adding some attributes to book-designer on open, to populate the data in the directive. Because the directives controller never gets called on open, the bindings are also not working. I get that maybe I have to populate the attributes using a front-end controller or something and that using jQuery, angular won’t know to digest (thus causing binding to not update).

```
         var productId = $(this).attr('data-product-id');
         var productName=$(this).attr('data-product-name');
         var bundleData=$(this).attr('data-bundle-data');
         $("##book-edit-modal").find('book-designer').attr("data-product-id",     productId )
         $("##book-edit-modal").find('book-designer').attr("data-product-name",   productName )
         $("##book-edit-modal").find('book-designer').attr("data-bundle-data",    getModalData() )
```

How can I pass information into this directive as well as have the directive be called at the time the modal is opened?

Comment: (1) angularJS normalizes attribute names, so you don't need to add data- to the front. (2) you're not setting product-id or product-name in your markup, so why would you expect to receive it in your controller (3), why even write all this unnecessary jQuery code, when angular provides you with perfectly good data binding?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Thanks for the reply. Adding data to the front is required for me regardless of anything Angular does unfortunately. product-id and product-name are there as empty strings in the actual version but I pulled a bunch of noise out of the example and those went with it. Are you saying that using jQuery to add values to those attributes will not be picked up by Angular if they are there? I would happily do away with the jQuery - but in this case - the directive exists inside a modal div, so that there can be many versions of it on the page.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship And those values are stored on the calling div inside a loop. So I'm retrieving the values and trying to add them to my directive on modal open. Which works. The values do get added, but Angulars bindings are never updated with the new values.

Comment: I think that the reason you are having to add data is because you're not using the element that comes in as a constructor argument to your controller or link function (it's not clear where the above code is). If you just use angular's native data binding, not only will you not have to junk up your code with unnecessary logic, it will update as expected. If you want to keep the junk, you'll need to watch the attributes and re-run your jquery code.